# How to make adduplex ads clickable in windows phone 8 ?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have implemented adduplex control exactly the same way as specified in adduplex website :

```
<adduplex:AdControl x:Name="adDuplexAd" 
                AppId="YOUR_AppId_HERE" 
                />
```

I used the nuget installation way and the following namespace :

```
xmlns:adduplex="clr-namespace:AdDuplex;assembly=AdDuplex.WindowsPhone"
```

The app displays ads perfectly however whenever the ads in the app are clicked , nothing happens , I tried searching on the adduplex blog , but didnt get anything .

I googled but still didn't get any substantial result . Is it some API error ?

Please help !

Comment: Hummm look if an another component is in front. I think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adControl might be covered by another element. Run the adControl in the Test mode and it will show any elements covering it in red on screen when debugging.

```
<adduplex:AdControl x:Name="adDuplexAd" 
            AppId="YOUR_AppId_HERE" 
            IsTest="True"
            />
```

or you can create the event handler for the `AdCovered` event and set a breakpoint and see if the ad is covered by another element.

```
<adduplex:AdControl x:Name="adDuplexAd" 
                AppId="YOUR_AppId_HERE" 
                AdCovered="adDuplexAd_AdCovered"
                />

private void adDuplexAd_AdCovered(object sender, AdDuplex.Models.AdCoveredEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Also you can add the event handler for the `AdClick` event and also set a break point and see if that is hit. ( same as the above code)